# check value of permissive_initialization in Jenkins Templating in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-template-engine

I am trying to do the following with Jenkins Templating -

```
node("Build-Node"){
    if(jte.permissive_initialization){
        jte.libraries.maven.build()
        jte.libraries.npm.build()    
    }
    else {
        build()
    }
}
```

The reason: I generally have microservices in my organization which are strictly either frontend or backend. There are some Microservices which have both of these components (in which case, I would like to build them both). My questions are -

1. is this a good design?
2. Can this be done in a better way?

Documentation: https://boozallen.github.io/sdp-docs/jte/2.2.2/primitives/primitive_namespace.html